# Sending text via Screen in Terminal OSX

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port, screen

I have connected an Arduino to a MacBookPro using USB, by using Screen (serial) in Terminal on the MBP.  I cannot figure out how to send text, via Screen, from the MBP to the Arduino.  Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything helpful in a very quick read of the 'screen' manual page. So, I'd be tempted to use the old 'cu' command.  Something like this might work to connect to the Arduino:

```
cu  -l /dev/cu.usbmodem0000001  -s 38400
```

(use whatever cu device your Arduino has, and pick whatever speed you want), then do:

```
~> filename
```

to send the named file to the Arduino.  When you're done, a "~." will end the session.

Check the man page for the 'cu' command - you can receive files, too, and run commands with their output sent to the serial line.

Have fun!